# properly & efficiently return an Eigen::Matrix (with lazy evaluation)

Tags: c++, eigen, google-benchmark

As explained in [the docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html), one should pay attention when using `auto` type deduction with eigen. e.g. the following function segfaults for me, and I'm okay with that:

```
struct MultiplyAdd{
  Eigen::Matrix<double, DIMS, DIMS> mult;
  Eigen::Matrix<double, DIMS, 1> add;
  auto counterExample(Eigen::Matrix<double, DIMS, -1> const& data) const {
    return (mult.sinh()*data).colwise() + add;
  }
};
```

As far as I understand the docs above, I can either spell out the return type as an actual matrix (and not a lazy evaluated expression) or use `eval()`.

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

constexpr int DIMS = 10;

struct MultiplyAdd{
  Eigen::Matrix<double, DIMS, DIMS> mult;
  Eigen::Matrix<double, DIMS, 1> add;
  Eigen::Matrix<double, DIMS, -1> transform(Eigen::Matrix<double, DIMS, -1> const& data) const {
    return ((mult*data).colwise() + add).eval();
  }
};


struct classic_worker{
  static auto dowork(Eigen::Matrix<double, DIMS, -1> const& data, MultiplyAdd const& trafo) {
    const auto flags = ((2.*trafo.transform(data)).row(2).array() > 1.7f).eval();
    return flags;
  }
};

struct allinline{
  static auto dowork(Eigen::Matrix<double, DIMS, -1> const& data, MultiplyAdd const& trafo) {
    const auto flags = ((2.*((trafo.mult * data).colwise() + trafo.add)).row(2).array() > 1.7f).eval();
    return flags;
  }
};

template <typename STRUCT>
static void quicktest(benchmark::State &state) {
  Eigen::Matrix<double, DIMS, -1> data = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(DIMS, state.range(0));

  Eigen::Matrix<double, DIMS, DIMS> m = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(DIMS, DIMS);
  Eigen::Matrix<double, DIMS, 1> a = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(DIMS, 1);

  MultiplyAdd trafo{m,a};

  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(STRUCT::dowork(data, trafo));
  }
}

// clang-format off
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(quicktest, classic_worker               )->UseRealTime()->DenseRange(20,320, 50);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(quicktest, allinline                    )->UseRealTime()->DenseRange(20,320, 50);
// clang-format on

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

In this longer example I have two implementations implementations of my `MultiplyAdd` and compare them with google-benchmark. In one case I do my operations in the `transform` method that I can put in a central header, in the other case I do all the lowlevel math on the "call site". In the example I only use row 2 of the computation. It appears

```
./iter_5 --benchmark_filter='.*(classic|all).*320.*' --benchmark_repetitions=10 --benchmark_report_aggregates_only
...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                               Time             CPU   Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
quicktest<classic_worker>/320/real_time_mean         3974 ns         3974 ns           10
quicktest<classic_worker>/320/real_time_median       3944 ns         3944 ns           10
quicktest<classic_worker>/320/real_time_stddev        121 ns          121 ns           10
quicktest<allinline>/320/real_time_mean              3308 ns         3308 ns           10
quicktest<allinline>/320/real_time_median            3285 ns         3285 ns           10
quicktest<allinline>/320/real_time_stddev            68.2 ns         68.2 ns           10
```

the all-at-call-site version is ~20% faster (with all the caveats of micro benchmarks).

My naive interpretation given the above link is that I'm avoiding lazy evaluation and needlessly compute all rows. (The speed difference appears independent of my choice for `DIMS` between 3 and 100, so I suspect my interpretation is wrong.)

What is the correct pattern to write functions that return eigen matrix types (in the docs I only saw mentions of function arguments)?

**EDIT**: I have a new example that's closer in observations to my real case

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

struct Trafo{
  Eigen::Quaternion<double> mult;
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> add;

  inline Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, -1> transform(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, -1> const& data) const noexcept {
    return ((mult.toRotationMatrix()*data).colwise() + add).eval();
  }
  inline auto counterExample(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, -1> const& data) const noexcept {
    return (mult.toRotationMatrix()*data).colwise() + add;
  }
};


struct classic_worker{
  static auto dowork(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, -1> const& data, Trafo const& trafo) {
    const auto flags = ((2.*trafo.transform(data)).row(2).array() > 1.7f).eval();
    return flags;
  }
};

struct counterExample_worker{
  static auto dowork(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, -1> const& data, Trafo const& trafo) {
    const auto flags = ((2.*trafo.counterExample(data)).row(2).array() > 1.7f).eval();
    return flags;
  }
};

struct allinline{
  static auto dowork(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, -1> const& data, Trafo const& trafo) {
    const auto flags = ((2.*((trafo.mult.toRotationMatrix() * data).colwise() + trafo.add)).row(2).array() > 1.7f).eval();
    return flags;
  }
};

template <typename STRUCT>
static void quicktest(benchmark::State &state) {
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, -1> data = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(3, state.range(0));

  Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> random = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(4, 1);
  Eigen::Quaternion<double> m{random(0), random(1), random(2), random(3)};
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> a = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(3, 1);

  Trafo trafo{m,a};

  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(STRUCT::dowork(data, trafo));
  }
}


// clang-format off
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(quicktest, counterExample_worker        )->UseRealTime()->DenseRange(20,320, 50);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(quicktest, classic_worker               )->UseRealTime()->DenseRange(20,320, 50);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(quicktest, allinline                    )->UseRealTime()->DenseRange(20,320, 50);
// clang-format on

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

There are three ways how to do my computation:

- a function (`counterExample` called by `counterExample_worker`) that doesn't call `eval` and thus lets a call site take care of evaluations - though this might (and seems to) lead to inefficient multiple evaluations
- a function (`transform` called by `classic_worker`) that calls `eval` and thus evaluates its expression (which might not be needed)
- all code at call site (done by `allinline`)

Compiled with g++8 and `-O3 -march=native` (and all in the same translation unit, so the compiler can do all the inlining it wants) I see the following timing table

```
quicktest<counterExample_worker>/320/real_time_mean        52612 ns        52612 ns           10
quicktest<counterExample_worker>/320/real_time_median      55218 ns        55217 ns           10
quicktest<counterExample_worker>/320/real_time_stddev       8501 ns         8501 ns           10
quicktest<classic_worker>/320/real_time_mean                 622 ns          622 ns           10
quicktest<classic_worker>/320/real_time_median               619 ns          619 ns           10
quicktest<classic_worker>/320/real_time_stddev              6.89 ns         6.89 ns           10
quicktest<allinline>/320/real_time_mean                      428 ns          428 ns           10
quicktest<allinline>/320/real_time_median                    426 ns          426 ns           10
quicktest<allinline>/320/real_time_stddev                   5.68 ns         5.67 ns           10
```

It appears, not calling `eval` is a bad idea here. However doing the transformation in its own function also comes at a price wrt writing everything in one line. So the question is rather: Is there a way to put the transformation here into separate functions without runtime slowdown? I do notice that (unfortunately) the results in this example depend heavily on the compiler and compilation flags (with `g++-8 -msse3` the difference between `allinline` and `classic_worker` vanishes, `clang++-10` appears to provide a faster `allinline` with `-msse3` and with `-march=native` …)

Comment: Your second example should work, if you keep all expressions lazy: https://godbolt.org/z/96njv3. In the example at the top, you are using a matrix function, from an [unsupported module](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__MatrixFunctions__Module.html#matrixbase_sinh) which probably does not work that way. Most importantly, you can't evaluate sub-expressions and expect the entire expression to work lazily.

Comment: And there is no "the correct way". It really depends on what you want to do, overall (in many cases lazy evaluation can lead to more operations, or it can bloat the compile time/the generated binary size with very little runtime reduction).